# How to use Power Automate "uriQuery()" function on an url that contains special characters

Tags: power-automate

Due to some odd circumstances I have the necessity to use `uriQuery()` in a Power Automate flow in order to extract the query string from an url.
This works as expected in most circumstances, except when the url contains special characters like accented letters, for example

```
http://www.example.com/peppers/Jalapeño/recipe #1.docx
```

In such cases the call triggers an error and the exception message shows a (partially) encoded version of my url (why?).

> The template language function 'uriQuery' expects its parameter to be a well-formed absolute URI. The provided value was '......'

Obviously the url was indeed a well-formed, absolute URI.

Since the error only triggers when the url contains special characters I assumed that I had to encode the value before calling `uriQuery()`, yet nothing I tried seems to work (for example encodeUriComponent() ). And as expected nothing I could find on the web mentioned a similar issue.

As a last attempt I am asking here - does `uriQuery()` support this use-case? And if it does... how?

Comment: What output are you wanting to obtain?

Comment: @Skin the query string  (if present). I didn't add any in my example because the issue isn't strictly tied to the query string itself. The issue arises because there are special characters in the folders / file names (this is SharePoint, so you can't control the names of the folder/documents users will create). uriQuery() should extract the query string from the url and return it (or an empty string if no query string is found) but in this case an error is thrown instead.

Comment: @Skin To be clear, I am not interested in an alternate way to extract the query string, I can find a workaround myself if I won't find any other solution. What I am asking here is what syntax I have to use to make uriQuery work as expected in this case too, or a reference to some credible source that say that such cases are not supported.